# How can I combine two methods that do the same thing but differ in type?

Tags: java, methods

I am fairly new to java programming and although I know the basics I feel as though my code is very long and unnecessary. I'm wondering if there is a way to combine my `elkStarter()` and `foxStarter()` methods into one `starter()` method so that I can reduce my code.

```
//Opening question, askes user to pick either an elk or fox
    public void systemStart(){
        for(int i =0;i<=100;i++){
           System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    }
    System.out.println("***STARTING NEW MOVEMENT MODEL***\n"+"-----------------------------------\n");
    iteration = 0;
    String animalType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                     ("Would you like an elk or a fox?");

    switch (animalType.toLowerCase()){
        case "elk": elkStarter("elk_1");
        break;
        case "fox": Foxtarter("fox_1"); 
        break;
        default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You didn't enter elk or fox..Please try again.");
        runAnotherModel();
        break;
    }
}

//systemStater goes to when "elk" is selected as the animal type.
public void elkStarter(){
    Elk elk_1 = new Elk();
    elk_1.namer("elk_1");
    System.out.println("You have just created an Elk called " + elk_1.name + ".\n" +
    "It has begun its life at (0,-0).");        
    elk_1.findPosition();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Lets let our new elk roam a bit, shall we?");


    int loop = 0;                 
    while(loop==0){
        String animalDirection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                     ("Which way should our elk move? (forward(f), backward(b), up(u), down(d)) or type stop(s) to quit.");
        switch(animalDirection.toLowerCase()){
            case "forward": case "f":
            elk_1.walkForward();
            elk_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "backward": case "b":
            elk_1.walkBackward();
            elk_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "up": case "u":
            elk_1.walkUp();   
            elk_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "down": case "d":
            elk_1.walkDown();
            elk_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "stop": case "s":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "GoodBye! Thanks for trying my model!");
            loop=1;
            break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "ummmm sorry that wasn't a direction...Please try again.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

//systemStater goes to when "fox" is selected as the animal type.
public void foxStarter(){
    Fox fox_1 = new Fox();
    fox_1.namer("fox_1");
    System.out.println("You have just created an Fox called " + fox_1.name + ".\n" +
    "It has begun its life at (0,-0).");        
    fox_1.findPosition();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Lets let our new fox roam a bit, shall we?");


    int loop = 0;                 
    while(loop==0){
        String animalDirection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                     ("Which way should our fox move? (forward(f), backward(b), up(u), down(d)) or type stop(s) to quit.");
        switch(animalDirection.toLowerCase()){
            case "forward": case "f":
            fox_1.walkForward();
            fox_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "backward": case "b":
            fox_1.walkBackward();
            fox_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "up": case "u":
            fox_1.walkUp();   
            fox_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "down": case "d":
            fox_1.walkDown();
            fox_1.findPosition();
            break;
            case "stop": case "s":
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "GoodBye! Thanks for trying my model!");
            loop=1;
            break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "ummmm sorry that wasn't a direction...Please try again.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes `Elk` and `Fox` have the a same parent class ,example - `Animal` , then I believe there are multiple ways to make the two starter functions a single one.

1. You can make the caller of the start function send in the object to work with , example -

   ```
   public void commonStarter(Animal animal) {
       ... // Do your logic on animal.
   }
   ```
2. Or you can send in an parameter to your `starter` function that would determine whether to create `Elk` or `Fox` , and then based on that, create the correct one in your class -

   ```
   public void commonStarter(boolean isElk) {
       Animal animal = None;
       if(isElk) {
           animal = new Elk();
       } else {
           animal = new Fox();
       }
       ... // Do your logic.
   }
   ```

Comment: The second option worked very well! Except I did have to put "new" in front of Elk() and Fox() when setting animal equal to them.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot that :) , fixed the answer , thanks.

Comment: I believe the question main issue still remains unsolved.

Comment: Sorry, why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a parent class/interface and then call the function using a boolean which defines whether the object is a Lion or an Elk. This is known as class hierarchy.

So you'd replace only one part of the code.

```
Animal somename;
if (isElk)
   somename = new Elk();
else
   somename = new Fox();
```

Where isElk would be a boolean value, which will be true if user wants to create a new Elk object, or false if the user wants to create a new Fox object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface and call the implementation you want based on user input.

Something like:

```
public interface Starter {
    void start();
}

public class ElkStarter implements Starter {

    private String name;
    // + constructor, getters, setters

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // ...
    }
}

// ...

public Starter getStarter(String animalType) {
    switch (animalType.toLowerCase()) {
      case "elk": return new ElkStart("elk_1");
      case "fox": return new FoxStart("fox_1");
      default: return null;
    }
}

public void systemStart() {
    // ...
    Starter starter = getStarter(animalType);
    // at this point, you do not know what Starter actually is
    if(starter != null) {
        starter.start();
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But how does this help shorten my code? Wouldn't I still have to have two seperate methods for my elk and fox instead of just one?

Comment: If they have some common pieces, you can also use an *abstract class* which would contain the common code.